# Cordova InAppBowser not loading DOM of result of each page after executescript

Tags: javascript, cordova

All,

Am using cordova inappbrowser. I load the a page uisng window.open. Then hook to loadstop and execute a javascript . The result of execution is another web page. Now I want to manipulate the document elements in that page. So i hook to another laodstop event, but that is not getting my second page. Some docs show , executescript returns an array, but not sure where the html dom is contained.

```
<script>
    var inAppBrowserRef;
    function OpenSRMS() {
        inAppBrowserRef = window.open('myink','_blank','location=no'); 
        inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstop', loginSRMS);
    }

    function loginSRMS() {
        if (inAppBrowserRef != undefined) {
            inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ code: "document.getElementById('userName').value = 'Training';" +
                                                            "document.getElementById('password').value = 'Training';" +
                                                            "document.getElementById(\"frm\").submit();"});

        }
        inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstop', INQCS);
    }

    function INQCS(){
        if (inAppBrowserRef != undefined) {
            inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ code: "alert('hello');"});
        }   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please properly format your question and remove the unnecessary `enter code here` parts

Comment: Sorry for that . @Capricorn

Comment: Mates...does anybody have an answer